# Coarser cyclic decomposition of Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

For a irreducible Markov chain with period $d$ there is a standard construction which shows that the state space can be partitioned into $d$ sets $C_1, \ldots, C_d$ such that $P(x,y)>0$ only if $x \in C_i$ and $y \in C_{1+i}$ (where $P$ is the transition probability and $(i+1)$ is to be taken modulo $d$).

It seems that the same construction would work if rather than taking $d$ to be the period of the chain we just take it to be some divisor of the period. So, for example, for a chain with period $4$ it is possible to break up the state space into two sets $C_1$ and $C_2$ with the above property.

Am I right in thinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.
But the $C_i$'s you get can be split again in stable subsets.

The point here is that for every $i$, $P^d$ restrained to $C_i$ is aperiodic when $d$ is the period of the chain.

In other words, $C_i$ can't be split in several subsets stable under a power of $P$, giving nice properties.